# Ruby on rails, How to create a radio button in form but not pass value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radio-button

recently I meet a issue, I am not sure how to do it.

there is 3 module , **User, Tenant and Purchase** in my case.

**User belongs to Tenant and Purchase belongs to User,
Tenant has_many purchase thourgh user.**

currently I need to create a tenant panel in _form of purchase. this is a list of radio to select which tenant I want to create purchase and show the user in that tenant.

**_form of Purchase**

```
  <%= panel("Tenant panel") do %>
    <div clase="checkbox">
      <% Tenant.all.each do |t| %>
        <%= f.group do %>
          <%= f.radio_button :tenant_id, :checked => (@current_tenant.id == t.id) %>
          <%= label :tenant_id, t.name%>
          <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

of course ,it doesn't work. because there is no tenant_id in Purchase. In order to no have any conflict, I couldn't add tenant_id . for me , this radio button is only a trigger.

what should I do in this case?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

`<%= collection_radio_buttons(:purchase, :user_id, Tenant.all, :user_id, :name) %>`

which roughly translates to: create a radio button for each `Tenant`, take their `user_id`  as value and display `name` as text. On submit it assigns the `user_id` of the selected tenant to the purchase (`@purchase` has to be available in a view)  you created. Remember to add the `user_id` to `Purchase` strong params :)

Comment: thanks , it works , but is there any ways to make them in different lines ?

Comment: It works out of the box for me, but if it's inline for you then you can try to pass the css class in html_options hash (see [here](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons)) and then style it in your CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`radio_button_tag`** instead of **`f.radio_button`**

```
radio_button_tag(name, value, checked = false, options = {})
```

Only you need to take care of the `name` of the field. 
For example, if you have a **`User`** model and the attribute is **`first_name`** then the name in HTML form would look like this **`user[first_name]`**.

In your case, it may be like this

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'user[tenant_id]', '' ,:checked => (@current_tenant.id == t.id) %>
```

Comment: thanks,  I have a error like this 
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)
: (